# How does Redis Makefile include header file prerequisites

Tags: c, makefile, redis

I was teaching myself GNU Make and thought a look at the Redis Makefile would teach me a thing or two about the tool.

The rule that compiles the source file to the object file is [here](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/Makefile#L196):

```
%.o: %.c .make-prerequisites
  $(REDIS_CC) -c $<
```

Notice that the suffix rule just mentions the C source file (with %.c) as a prerequisite.

But if I add a echo in the middle and run make:

```
%.o: %.c .make-prerequisites
  echo $^
  $(REDIS_CC) -c $<
```

Then the first few lines of the output from make is like below:

```
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/cltpadmin/code/redis/src'
echo adlist.c .make-prerequisites adlist.h zmalloc.h
adlist.c .make-prerequisites adlist.h zmalloc.h
CC adlist.o
```

How did `make` know that `adlist.c` depends on `adlist.h` and `zmalloc.h`?

Comment: Maybe that is detailed in another part of the makefile?

Comment: I have read through the Makefile and cannot find it. Hence the question.

Comment: Prerequisites for a makefile are combined from every location where the target is mentioned. So `tgt: pr1`, `tgt: pr2`, `tgt: pr3` would combine such that make knows that `tgt` has `pr1`, `pr2`, and `pr3` as prerequisites. The output (voluminous as it is) from `make -qp` might be of use in finding these other locations.

Comment: Look at the `Makefile.dep` file included on line 134 of that makefile and the `dep` target that generates it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prerequisites in question come from line one of the [`Makefile.dep`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/Makefile.dep#L1) included makefile (included on line 134).

The `dep` target on line 136 generates that file.

This was a fairly common (though entirely avoidable) step for using the compiler to generate the necessary header file includes. This static method also has issues with conditional header includes I believe.

To clarify, the "avoidable" part of this is that it need not be a separate step and a static dependency file at all. See [Advanced Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) for details about this idea.

Comment: Oh I missed that file. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea why the author has defined the .make-prerequisites target? Looks like it is not needed.

Comment: @ardsrk I'd have to look into it more but it appears to be involved in persisting configuration settings to another included makefile when you use the right flags. Look at the three different `.make-prerequisites` targets.